# Sending state with react router not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using `react version ^16.8.1` and `react-router-dom version ^4.3.1` in my project.
I am trying to send piece of state with react router like this:

```
      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/',
        state: {
          successMessage: this.generateSuccessMessage(payload)
        }
      });
```

In the other component I am trying to get that state and send down as a prop to a child component like this:

```
successMessage={this.props.location.state ? this.props.location.state.successMessage : null}
```

But, I keep getting `null` every time I am triggering push. I have checked the `state` in the react dev tools, and tested with Jest, but both show that `state` is not being forwarded to the other component. Below are the relevant routes. I am pushing the state from `OppgaveEditor` to history, and trying to get it in the `Dashboard` component.

```
     <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Redirect to="/dashboard" />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" render={(props) => <Dashboard user={this.state.user} {...props} ><OppgaveDashboard/></Dashboard>}/>} />
          <Route path="/oppgave-editor/:id" render={(props) => <OppgaveEditor user={this.state.user} {...props} />}/>
          <Route component={NotFound}/>
     </Switch>
```

What am I doing wrong, how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show how you forward the `location` to the component in your route ?

Comment: I have added the routes configuration to the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you lose the `state` during the redirection to '/'. You need to forward it.

It should give you something like this:

```
 <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Redirect to={{
      pathname: '/',
      state: this.props.location.state
    }}
 />
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, if I change the  routing directly to oppgaver component, then I get the state. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gael's answer, I found this approach that worked for me:

```
<Route exact path="/home" render={ props => <Home {...props} />} />
```